# rails templating for subdomains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, ruby-on-rails-4, erb, subdomain

A webbapplication has 3 subdomains, www., mobile. and admin.
They all share the same business logic but are different in the views (different layouts).
How can I in rails create this structure so they all become "independent" in their views/layout?

One specific problem I have is that when creating controllers for the admin section of the site, and creating controllers (using rails generate controller) for the www section of the site, magically some javascript files and css files are being added to the assets directory and all of them included when using the following code;

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

They seem to be independent from each other.
This results in that the www version view also includes admin related javascript and css.
I want to encapsle them so each route with the subdomain constraint uses respective javascript and css and they all dont get mixed up together.
I could just remove the auto-tags for this, but it feels more of a quickfix/hack and I am sure there is a better approach to achieve this.

I am very new to rails but have quite some experience with PHP so just want to get this into place so I can move along.

Comment: you have several questions at the same time. that's not a good way to ask here. in terms of layouts, you can change it with the controllers layout method. asset compilation is a completely independent topic. i would advise you to use 3 different route files for all your apps.

Comment: you can have a look at one of my opensource projects that have a multi-tennancy approach, so they might answer some of your questions https://github.com/phoet/on_ruby